# Java - Determine common path for every user that runs my application

Tags: java, path, system, getproperty

I have created an application (You can find the entire thing here to see the problem yourself: https://github.com/Tressos-Aristomenis/Snakes-And-Ladders-JavaFX-from-scratch !) and I have put some background music.

I am actually using a folder called "music" that contains all the tracks. In my pc "music" 's location is at: ***D:\MyWork\PersonalStuff\Programming\Refactored_SnakesAndLadders_v2\Refactored_SnakesAndLadders_v2\src\music***.

If I use this path **in my PC** to specify where the tracks are, it is working fine. Obviously this is not common to any other PC. I found that "**System.getProperty("user.dir")**" specifies the location of where the java was run from.

Using the path: `private final String TRACKS_PATH = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\music";` actually works at my PC as well in a more dynamically way. Now the "music" folder can be found no matter where the project is.

**PROBLEM**:

Some friends of mine have downloaded the .jar file, even the entire code + the jar and the application is not running; which means there is an **NullPointerException** at lines:

```
TRACKS_DIRECTORY = new File(TRACKS_PATH);
TRACKLIST = TRACKS_DIRECTORY.listFiles();
```

*TRACKLIST is an array of files.* Obviously TRACKS_DIRECTORY is null cause the path is incorrect.

***Any help on how to determine a common path for every user that runs my application?***

Comment: Ideally you should be putting in System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") directory which is common and accessible to your application.

Comment: Could you be more specific ??

Comment: Updated my comment.

Comment: Other users will not have this path tho, no matter where they download the jar ... the music folder must be tracked

Comment: "Some friends of mine have downloaded the .jar file" - did they download the music files as well? Or are those inside the .jar?

Comment: Is it always the same set of files, and never changes?  If yes, include the files within the jar as resources.  The code can load the resources from the jar instead of relying on an external path.

Comment: Thomas: I was clear on this part. They both downloaded the entire code + the .jar or other times just the .jar
Both cases didn't work.

Andrew, could you provide some tutorial on how to do this ?

Comment: I am sharing only the src folder. Resources must be outside of src!